# How many k member teams can be created from n people

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**The prompt asks you to find the number of k member teams that can be created from n people.**

The number of teams that can be created depends on the number of people left after creating the first group, considering there are 10 people, and we make teams of 4, we have 2 teams and 2 people get left out, so we must only choose so many members in a team that all n people can be accommodated.

The way I went on about solving the problem was to put one person in each team to begin with, since we can't have a team with no players, so we have $n\choose k$. Now we are left with **n - k** people, since number of teams is equal to number of players already in a team, now we can do something like $${n\choose k}(n-k)^k$$ to divide rest of the **n-k** players into **k** teams. Is this the correct way to approach this problem?

What I don't understand is that this method considers we already know how many teams there are, how would we solve if we don't know how many teams exist. Is this similar to finding all possible binary sequences with n zeros and k ones, since we don't know how many sequences exist, but we know what goes in those sequences. Applying that formula here, $${n + 1 \choose k} $$ when $k \leq n+1$ and 0 when $k > n + 1$

Comment: Each team has $k$ members, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Each team must have $k$ players, so $k$ divides $n$. Then can you see why

$$\binom{n}{n-k} \binom{n-k}{n-2k} \binom{n-2k}{n-3k} \ldots$$
works? At the first stage, we pick $n-k$ people to stay behind, and the rest form a team. In the next stage, we pick $n-2k$ people to stay behind, and the rest form a new team, and so on.

Now, using the suggestive notation I used above, let's simplify:

$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} \cdot \frac{(n-k)!}{(n-2k)!k!} \frac{(n-2k)!}{(n-3k)!k!} \ldots = \frac{(mk)!}{k!^{m}}$$

where $m = n/k$.

Comment: Say we have 10 players and 5 teams, I figured out that it would be nCk which would be equal to 252 and in your case m would be 10/5 = 2 and using your rule, we would get (2*5)! over $5!^2$ which would be also equal to 252.. So nCk is correct and the shortest form of solving it, right??

Comment: nCk is not algebraically equal to what I put however. That only works when you have 2 per team.

Comment: Ahh alright thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be seen as arranging the set of players a line and then giving the first $k$ players a jersey with a $1$ on it, then next $k$ players a jersey with a $2$ on it, and so on.

Let $m$ be the number of teams. There are $(mk)!$ ways to arrange the players. For each team, we overcounted $k!$ times, however(the order of the players doesn't matter).

Thus, the number of ways is

$$\frac{(mk)!}{k!^m}$$

Comment: Since $ m = \frac{n}{k}$ and then you multiply by $k!$.. Then why don't we just simplify it and say $n!$ right away? Sorry I am just trying to clearly understand it and simplify it as much as possible

Comment: You can do that. I am just making it clearer by ignoring $n$ and using $m$, the number of teams, and $k$, the number of players per team.

Comment: Cool, cool, voted for both of your answers. Thanks!!

Comment: Hey again! I am practicing before my discrete mathematics test after tomorrow, so I have one more question to make sure I understand this clearly. Shouldn't the denominator have $m!^k$ instead of  $k!^m$? Question 127 here says so http://www.careerbless.com/aptitude/qa/permutations_combinations5.php

Comment: The problems are slightly different.


The site and my answer agree if you consider the teams *distinct*(Team 1, Team 2, and so on). $k$ is the number of players per team, which is $4$. $m$ is the number of teams, which is $3$. The right answer here would be $(3 \cdot 4)! / 4!^3$.

The site does not distinguish between the groups, so you divide once more by $m!$.

Comment: Ohh yeah I know about the order part but I just miscalculated this, I am sorry and thanks again!!